# LINQ Getting The Next Row ID?

Tags: c#, linq

Lets say I have a table with RowId, and Value:

```
1 valueA
2 valueB
3 valueC
4 valueD
```

Then let's say I delete the 4th row:

```
1 valueA
2 valueB
3 valueC
```

So the next row ID will be 5.  Because the 4th row was deleted, I can't simply find the last row in the table and add 1 to get the next row ID.  How can I obtain the next row ID?

Thanks!

Comment: why would you need to know what the next autogenerated id is?

Comment: This is to create table relations when inserting a new row into a table.

Comment: That should be handled through SQL automatically. Look into setting up primary keys that are auto-incremented. Otherwise just getting the last record and doing a +1 would work, although it isn't ideal

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?t=41676

Comment: this is backwards.  Assuming you could guess what the next row id is, there is the possibility of a collision if you insert the child records first.  Also, you preclude the possibility of enforcing foreign key relationships on the child records if they are inserted before the parent record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In LinqToSQL, if two classes each have a PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY columns and have a connecting association (created by FKey in the database or manually in the designer), you can do your two related items insert like this:

```
Customer c = new Customer() {Name = "Bob"};
Order o = new Order() {Customer = c, Quantity = 5};

myDataContext.InsertOnSubmit(c);
  //submit changes will insert c and o
  //  in the right order and with all id's populated.
myDataContext.SubmitChanges();
  //the id's are populated 
int customerID = c.CustomerID;
int orderID = o.OrderID;
customerID = o.CustomerID;
```

Comment: +1 exactly - let Linq-to-SQL handle all those messy details and don't worry about guessing ID's ahead of time!

Comment: I think you'd have to InsertOnSubmit(o) if you want both objects inserted.  c doesn't reference o.  Right?

Comment: c references o through an Orders property created by the association.  This same association created the Order.Customer property.

Answer (score 2):

After you insert a new row you will get the row ID.  I don't see why you would need it before you insert it!